# Optimal Cutpoint for Predicted Results from Kaplan Meier and Cox Regression

Tags: survival, prediction, cox-model, regression-strategies, kaplan-meier

Is there anyway to get the optimal cutpoint for predicted survival probabilities of the aforementioned survival analysis approaches?

Something like the optimal cutpoint from `ROC` (`Epi` package) for logistic regression.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such cutpoints do not exist.  Any attempt to force the choice of a cutpoint will result in non-reproducibility by others.  The only rational way to get a cutpoint would be to know the utility/loss/cost function, and you could choose a cutpoint that would optimize expected utility.  It is very important to note however that each patient would have a different cutpoint.  So even then the idea of seeking a cutpoint is poorly motivated.

I've written about this in detail in Chapter 18 of [Biostatistics for Biomedical Research](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/ClinStat)